# MVC providing runtime image not save on disk to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My MVC app creates images at runtime that I do NOT need to save on the disk.

What's the best way to send those to the requesting browser?
Note that the images will never be the same, so there is no reason to save them on disk first.

The server will draw the random image and will return the image to the calling client. I'm trying to understand what the best format for this type of operation is (bitmap, image ...) so that the streaming back to the server is as smooth and as fast as possible.

Comment: Are they produced as the result of a request from the browser? Some code would help.

Comment: Too broad. There are many samples on the site -pick some and try. Commonly found along read image from db...

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the bytes of the bitmap, then it's easy to return it to the client

```
public ActionResult GetImage()
{
    byte[] byteArray = MagicMethodToGetImageData();
    return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Moreover, if you want to return the image plus some data, you can encode the bytes as base64 and wrap it in a JSON like this:

```
public ActionResult GetImage()
{
    byte[] byteArray = MagicMethodToGetImageData();
    var results = new 
    {
        Image = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray),
        OtherData = "some data"
    };

    return Json(results);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use the [FileContentResult class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to read the file content and directly show it or offer to download. A solution could look like this:

```
private FileContentResult getFileContentResult(string name, bool download = true)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        // don't forget to set the appropriate image MIME type 
        var result = new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(name), "image/png");
        if (download)
        {
            result.FileDownloadName = Server.UrlEncode(name);
        }
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The use this method in some *Action* like this:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string name)
{
    return getFileContentResult(name, true);
    // or use the image directly for example in a HTML img tag
    // return getFileContentResult(name);
}
```

The class is pretty robust and fast - I have made good experience using it for exactly the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending them in the same page where you create it, then you can modify your Response to send it directly.

```
//After having your bitmap created...

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.PNG);
bmp.Dispose();
byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
Response.ContentLength = data.Length;

using(var str = Response.GetResponseStream())
    str.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

Response.End();
```

Comment: I was expecting to send the image on a ViewBag or similar since I have lots of other info to send back to the browser. If I put the bytes[] data in a ViewBag, do you know the code to display that on the browser img tag?